# Need to hide the files which are being used from Assets folder

Tags: java, android

I am using an offline application which has html,css and js files in the assets folder.When i install the application on a device a can access those files from **file:////storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp.name/files**. I need a way to hide these files at it causes a security issue. I load my app from UI webview through one of the files in assets folder

Comment: so you can store it in Asset folder.

Comment: Do you know that getting the content of apk is as simple as extracting .zip file? Not only the assets, drawables, etc..,  looking at your source also does not take more than 2 minutes. If you have CRITICAL SECURITY issue, you need to change your strategy. Thats it.

Comment: `When i install the application on a device a can access those files from file:////storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp.name/files. `. No. Nonsense. Of course not. That is not the assets folder at all.

Comment: `I load my app from UI webview through one of the files in assets folder` ???? Dont understand a word of this.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a way to hide these files at it causes a security issue

First, they are not files. They are assets. They are stored in the APK file, not as files on the filesystem.

Second, you cannot "hide" assets. They are in your APK, and anyone can take your APK and retrieve those assets. It is unlikely that anyone will bother to do this.

Comment: Is there any other private path or something i can place my files in rather than keeping them in assets to secure the files from not being accessible by end users

Comment: @user6000866: Keep them on the server, and never have them on the client. Anything else can be obtained by at least some users. This is not significantly different than how Web apps/sites work -- sufficiently-talented users can get at anything that is exposed to the Web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to hide assets.

As a workaround, you can do the following:

1. Copy the content of your HTML, CSS and JS files in a long text String.
2. When app is loaded for the first time, load the string content and create a `Private` file at runtime and save it in `Internal Storage`.
3. Files written in Internal storage by an app can not be accessed by any other apps, including a file explorer. so they are safe from misuse.

use this code to store private file in internal storage:

```
String filename = "yourfile.html";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is there any other private path or something i can place my files in rather than keeping them in assets to secure the files from not being accessible by end users

Answer (score 0):

To protect assets folder information If the `html` file is either `css` or `js`, the easiest way is to:
Write your code in the `html editor` first, and then enter it in a `Java class` as follows :

```
 public class Content{
    public static final String  myContent ="<!DOCTYPE html> ... </html> "
```

And then call through the `loadDataWithBaseURL` method

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,Content.myContent, "text/html" , "UTF-8" ,null);
```

And you can call  `js` and `css` in html code :

```
 ...
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="file:///android_asset/css/custom.css" /> 
 <script src="file:///android_asset/js/code.jquery.js"></script>                                                                                   
</head>
```